# GitHub - How to solve the Lint Code Base fail in PR

Tags: github, pull-request

I am trying to make a pull request on GitHub, and one of the checks i.e. Lint Code Base is failing for some reason. I would like to know why it is happening and how to solve this problem.
[image]

Comment: Does clicking on "Details" give more information?

Comment: no it does not @GregHNZ

Comment: Can you share a link to the PR, so we can see for ourselves?

Comment: Link to PR: https://github.com/avinashkranjan/Amazing-Python-Scripts/pull/1806